# how to get the value at specific column and specific row in jtable by a mouse clicked

Tags: java, swing, jtable, mouselistener

hey here i stuck in my program.Actually i have a jtable and i want to select the value of specific row and specific coloumn every time when a mouse is clicked over the row of jtable...
here is my class which i am using:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

public class jtable extends JFrame implements MouseListener    
{

PdfViewer3 pdfViewer3;    
String value;    
JTable table;    
//Vector dataVector;    
public jtable() throws ClassNotFoundException
    {
        ArrayList columnNames = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList data = new ArrayList();    
        //  Connect to an MySQL Database, run query, get result set
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/search_imgr_data";
        String userid = "root";
        String password = "root";
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM mission_db limit 70060,5";
        // Java SE 7 has try-with-resources
        // This will ensure that the sql objects are closed when the program
        // is finished with them
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection( url, userid, password );
            Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( sql );

            ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
            int columns = md.getColumnCount();

            //  Get column names
            for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++)
            {
                columnNames.add( md.getColumnName(i) );
            }

            //  Get row data
            while (rs.next())
            {
                ArrayList row = new ArrayList(columns);    
                for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++)
                {
                    row.add( rs.getObject(i) );
                }    
                data.add( row );
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            System.out.println( e.getMessage() );
        }    
        // Create Vectors and copy over elements from ArrayLists to them
        // Vector is deprecated but I am using them in this example to keep
        // things simple - the best practice would be to create a custom defined
        // class which inherits from the AbstractTableModel class
        Vector columnNamesVector = new Vector();
        Vector dataVector = new Vector();    
        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++)
        {
            ArrayList subArray = (ArrayList)data.get(i);
            Vector subVector = new Vector();
            for (int j = 0; j < subArray.size(); j++)
            {
                subVector.add(subArray.get(j));
            }
            dataVector.add(subVector);
        }    
        for (int i = 0; i < columnNames.size(); i++ )
            columnNamesVector.add(columnNames.get(i));

        //  Create table with database data
        table = new JTable(dataVector, columnNamesVector)
        {
            public Class getColumnClass(int column)
            {
                for (int row = 0; row < getRowCount(); row++)
                {
                    Object o = getValueAt(row, column);    
                    if (o != null)
                    {
                        return o.getClass();
                    }
                }    
                return Object.class;
            }
        public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int colIndex) {
          return false;
     }

        };
         table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
           public void MouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
               System.out.println("IN listener");
               table.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);
               table.setColumnSelectionAllowed(true);
               if (e.getClickCount() != 0)
                {
                  JTable target = (JTable)e.getSource();
                  int row = target.getSelectedRow();
                  int column = 1;    
                value = (String)target.getValueAt(row, column);
                //value= ((Vector)rowData.elementAt(row)).elementAt(column);
                Thread runner = new Thread(){
                    public void run(){
                        //pdfViewer3 = new PdfViewer3();
                        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                        pdfViewer3.setVisible(true);}});    
                        pdfViewer3.initComponents1(value);    
                    }
                };runner.start();
                }    
            }    
    });
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
        getContentPane().add( scrollPane );    
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        getContentPane().add( buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH );
    }

   public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException         
{

        jtable frame = new jtable();            
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );            
        frame.pack();            
        frame.setVisible(true);
   }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }
}
```

Comment: the problem is that i m nt getting the values at mouse clicked to use in another class

Answer (score 5):

- read Oracle tutorial [How to use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html), becase there are a few mistakes
- `MouseEvents` are very good described in part [Specifying Tool Tips for Cells](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#celltooltip), incl working code example

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Answer (score 3):

Why would you read the data from the database into an ArrayList and then copy the data to a Vector? Just load the data directly into a Vector.

```
table.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);
table.setColumnSelectionAllowed(true);
```

The above code does not look correct. I would get rid of it. At the very least is should NOT be in the MouseListener. If this really is the behaviour you want, then those statements should be executed when you create the table, otherwise I would guess that when you change the selection properties AFTER you click on a cell, then you would lose the last selection values.

```
public void MouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
```

Or maybe the problem is simple that you use "M" on the `mouseClicked` method. It should be "m". You should use the @Override annotation when overriding methods to make sure you don't make typing mistakes.

```
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
```